# GoToWebinar for Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation

Can the GoToWebinar application work on Ubuntu's operation system?

I am seeing that it is not applicable on this, is there a way around the problem?

Comment: Well, it has an Android app, though, if I'm not mistaken. I know it probably hasn't helped you much, but Android is technically Linux :D I have watched some webinars using my smartphone (because I'm a Linux guy) and it's pretty practical. Cheers and good luck! GoToWebinar App:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.citrix.saas.gotowebinar&hl=en

Answer (score 2):

No, GoToWebinar [doesn't support Linux](http://community.gotomeeting.com/gotomeeting/topics/develop_gotowebinar_for_all_32_bit_and_64_bit_linux_operating_systems) as of yet.

There is hope, since [GoToMeeting has a working WebViewer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56294/how-to-use-gotomeeting-in-linux) with [requirements](http://support.citrixonline.com/en_US/gotomeeting/all_files/GTM130019#What_are). But as of right now there is no support for GoToWebinar.

Answer (score -1):

Just saw this, and thought I'd pass it on:

http://support.citrixonline.com/en_US/Webinar/help_files/G2W030003?Title=GoToWebinar+Support+for+Chromebook+and+Linux+Attendees

won't have an opportunity to try it out until maybe next week.